# Session in other page don't display the value

Tags: php

I have a page with checkbox, every checkbox can be set on true, if on true, the products id is added across an ajax inside an array.

I look my ajax and it work's well.

my ajax

```
 session_start();

  if (is_array($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['productsCompare'] = $_POST['product_id'];
  }
```

`$_SESSION['productsCompare']` return an array with the products id values

After selected some checkbox, if I click on button to go another page and I wrote `var_dump($_SESSION['productsCompare'])`, I have null as result.

Do you any idea to resolve this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: is $_POST['product_id'] actually an array? if productsCompare is null that means its not hitting the set block or you're posting null data to the form anyways.

Comment: Why check if it is array and then if it exists?

Comment: @TimHinz, I do not use a form (I can't), every checkbox is put in array (product_id[]: 12
product_id[]: 11
product_id[]: 10
product_id[]: 9)  accross the ajax (that's the reason I use an ajax) and stored inside the session  $_SESSION['productsCompare'] . Now if i go on another page I lost $_SESSION['productsCompare']

Comment: On _another page_ you have `session_start()` and no errors???

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that on the other page where you want to get the values from the  $_SESSION variable, you have started the session by calling the `session_start();` and this is the very first line of your file.

**EDIT:**
Suppose I have two files:

```
<?php
session_start();

// index.php
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';


<?php
session_start();

// sess.php
var_dump($_SESSION['foo']);
```

It prints `/sess.php:4:string 'bar' (length=6)`

So please make sure that you have started the session on the other file as well.